Messed up movie about 3 or 4 teenage kids who get picked on in school
I'm trying to remember the name of this movie but I can't.In the movie on of the characters is a fat kid who's dad beats him while another kid is a genius who drops acid all the time and his parents are rich, Lastly the third kid is a black kid adopted by white people and is neighbors with the fat kid.  In the end of the movie the kids end up shooting up their high school, I think the name had world in it somewhere. Can anyone Identify this movie?

Could it be "Mad World" from 2010?
http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0451108/?ref_=fn_al_tt_2
